# A link to a page including an anchor doesn't go to that anchor - URL gets changed

Tags: permalinks

My WordPress site is set up with "Post name" permalinks.

Now I created an anchor in every page at a certain place:

But I find that when I try to link to that page, and its anchor, like this:

http://example.com/mypost#my_anchor

.. it doesn't work.  The URL gets converted on the fly to:

http://example.com/mypost/#my_anchor

... so the link never goes to the correct part of the page.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong - how to correct this?

(Note: I did see a very similar question where someone had this a problem after they put an *extra* slash on the end, *after* the anchor part, but I'm *not* doing that.)

Thanks.

PS It doesn't work if I use a div with an id instead of the anchor, either.

Comment: The link should work the same with or without the leading slash, but the trailing slash does break it. I just tested all three versions. Something else is wrong but I can't tell what from the question. Named anchors are not supported in HTML5 so whatever you do, use an `id`.

Comment: I used an anchor with an ID and a div's ID but both exhibit the above behaviour.

Comment: And I tested both cases and both work fine. There is something peculiar to your setup-- code, browser, OS, something-- that is causing this not to work correctly. It doesn't help that you provided a dummy sitename. That has zero debugging value.

Comment: Seems I'm not alone in finding this behaviour: http://bit.ly/19cBRJP - except I din not have a trailing slash, as that poster didn't to begin with though he kinda forgot that.